# What two input functions satisify an output between 0 and 1?

Tags: functions

What are common functions that take two input variables and make the output between 0 and 1?

Question is as simple as that, two inputs and one output, output needs to stay between 0 and 1!

Comment: I think more information would be helpful...the constant $\frac 12$ works.  As does $F(x,y)=\sin (xy)$  or $e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}$.  or $\frac 1{10x^2+173y^2+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

This question is way way way **way way way** too broad. There are infinitelly many such functions.

Examples:

- $f(x,y)=|\sin(x)|$
- $f(x,y)=\sin^2(x)\sin^2(y)$
- $f(x,y)=1$
- $f(x,y) = e^{-x^2-y^2}$

There are *many* more. Without further details, it's hard to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: Indeed, given any function $f(x,y)$ the function $g(x,y)=\dfrac{|f(x,y)|}{|f(x,y)|+c}$ satisfies the conditions for any positive constant $c.$

Comment: Two inputs are have domains between 0 and 2. I have a more detailed version on my other questions but wanted to get a broad sense since that was not getting much response. Thank you!

Comment: Note that for any functions valued in $(0,1)$ you get another function valued in $(0,1)$ by multiplying them.

Answer (score 0):

$$f (x,y)=(x+y)-\lfloor x+y \rfloor $$

Comment: You might want to consider leaving a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

For any lower and upper bounded function $f$, say:

$$m \le f(x,y) \le M$$

then the "normalized" function $g$:

$$g(x,y) = \frac{f(x,y)-m}{M-m}$$

will do the job. **So any common bounded function** can be scaled very simply to satisfy the condition. If you don't fear saturation, then:

$$g(x,y) = \min\left( \max\left(f(x,y),0\right),1\right)$$

does it as well. A useful class of such functions can be found among [sigmoid functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) (some take values in $[-1,1]$ but this can be fixed easily), like the logistic curve:

[image: logistic curve]

You also have a handful of cumulative distribution functions from [probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions).